# PDO with Odbc driver - Query fails only using prepare()

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo

What we have to sum it up is a PDO connection, where we first prepare() a query and then we execute it with a few params.

```
$slug1 = "store1";
$slug2 = "it";

$o = new PDO('odbc:Store_tasks');
$stmt = $o->prepare("SELECT BLALALALA.....JOINS BLALALA WHERE S.slug = ? AND P.slug = ?");
$result = $stmt->execute(array($slug1, $slug2));
```

This fails, but what i found is that if i use:

```
$o->query("SELECT BLALALALA.....JOINS BLALALA WHERE S.slug = 'store1' AND P.slug = 'it'");
```

Works(building the query string by my own)!. Unfortunately i don't have remote access to this or the exact error message; but i need some ideas of what could be wrong to try to fix this once i get there.

These are Windows/MS Sql servers. (not of my preference or experience at all).
It could be the charset? Setting the DSN to someting like

```
'odbc:Store_tasks&charset=utf8'
```

Or maybe using:

```
PDOStatement::bindParam to set up some params?
```

The thing is that on our testing servers also Windows/MSSql it works without any issue(versions may differ).

Any other suggestion i could try?

Comment: You have to use bindParams!

Comment: For real? that could be the difference? Sad news if true, that was just an example... there is more than one query using that, fml

Comment: @Ron you should set your connection to display errors, also try with named placeholders. worth a try since your code should work